# Algorithm Theory [ i/2 loop ]

Tags: algorithm

Hey guys I have this question in Algorithm Theory course and I can't find an equation of T(n):

```
S = 0
 While i > 1 Do
  S = S + i
  i = i / 2
 EndWhile
```

I need the function of the time (number of steps).

Comment: @dyesdyes  I tried a lot to understand I'm new in this science forgive me.

Comment: Don't be ashamed, it just seems like you are expecting us to do your homework. You should at least explain what you don't understand, struggle with so we can explain you properly, and not just give you the answer that you will copy paste.

Comment: This not my homework, I prepare my self for the next lecture and I try to understand the new material on my own, cause I need to be special in my class. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the algorithm starts from `i=n`, the complexity of this function can be denoted as:

```
T(n) = O(1) + T(n/2)
```

Each iteration requires constant operations, and when it is left - you reduce the size of the iterator by half, giving you total of T(n/2) operations left.

---

When this is established, here is question for you: what is the complexity of this function under the big-O notation?